# HTML/CSS: How to achieve the following center-left alignment?

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

#### Short version

I want to position text inside an element (fixed width) in such a way, that if it is short enough, it will be centered, but if it's too long to fit, it will be left-aligned, and the end of the text will be cut off (via `overflow: none`). In this case there will be a tooltip (via `title=""`) with the full text. How can I do it?

#### Complete version

The element I'm referring to is a title beneath a picture. Since there are many pictures side-by-side, I don't want the titles to overlap or anything (they are absolutely positioned beneath the picture with fixed width and height). For a title it will look better if it's centered, but a lengthy string with `overflow:none` that gets both ends cut off because of centering will look bad. Currently I have this:

```
<div class="ImageTitle">
    <table style="margin: auto">
        <tr><td title="The title">The title</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is hackish to say the least, but I can't seem to get it working with simple `DIV`s and `SPAN`s. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should do what you want:

```
div.ImageTitle {
    width: 100px; /* or whatever */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XpDyD/).

Note that I'm assuming the removal of the (unnecessary `table`), if the table's still there then its css will override that of the `div.imageTitle`.

While this **doesn't** conditionally assign either `text-align: center` or `text-align: left`, the former (`text-align: center;`) will simply move from the centre of the element to the left margin of the element naturally (unless `text-direction` is set to something other than `ltr`), and over-flow on the right. To ensure that it remains on only one line, I've used `white-space: nowrap` to remove wrapping.

For the tooltip I'm afraid *that* will have to be hardcoded into the `div` (or whatever other element you use), since there's no way to use html so that it can work with if/else statemnts. If you're willing to use JavaScript then it's possible, but not with *just* html/css.

Comment: In the words of the great wise ancients: WTF?! Yes, I admit, I never tried simply `center` ing the text, because I though it would remain true to the centering constraint and cut off both ends. While this does solve my problem in an astoundingly elegant way, I still wonder - why? I could not find this behavior in CSS2 spec. Is this official?

Comment: I...don't know about 'official,' but it's certainly *consistent* =)

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? (I'm sorry, it's late here, I'm tired and unconcentrated)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.outer {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.inner {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:8em;text-align: center; border: 1px solid black">
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
      Short cap
  </span>
</div>
<p />
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
      A very long caption
  </span>
</div>

</div>
```

There's got to be a proper way to fix height, though.

Comment: No down-vote, but *why* do you need to 'fix height'? Just use [`white-space: nowrap;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do this is with JavaScript.